# LINQy way to check if any objects in a collection have the same property value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Agent with a property Id

Given a collection of Agents I need to check if any of them have duplicate Ids.

I am currently doing this with a hash table but am trying to get Linq-ified, what's a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Similar to Y Low's approach,

**Edited:**

```
 var duplicates = agents.GroupBy(a => a.ID).Where(a=>a.Count() > 1);

 foreach (var agent in duplicates)
 {
         Console.WriteLine(agent.Key.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Hmm, GroupBy, interesting.  Wouldn't this work then:
bool b = (agents.GroupBy(a=>a.Id)).Count() == agents.Count();

Comment: Just posted an update, just combine the two (GroupBy and Where) to get the key of the duplicate object...

Comment: Ha - comparing the number of groups to the number of elements. That's an inspired idea.

Comment: I'm wondering whether grouping would be a bit less efficient than the Any() method, though, since Any() gives up as soon as it finds a match, whereas grouping has to visit every element.

Comment: Matt...we'd have to test that I guess. I just approached it like a SQL problem. I'm a db guy, so I love Linq for it's Sql-like approach to problems like this...

Comment: Yeah from an SQL perspective it's GROUP BY vs WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Glad you like it Matt.  You're probably right about efficiency but I find this more readable.

Comment: As an aside, the Parallel Extensions to .NET are going to make stuff like this very interesting (and fast)...!

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I just compared the two methods we've struck upon in this thread. First I defined a helper class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID;
}
```

... and then made a big list of instances with a random ID:

```
var list = new List<Foo>();

var r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) list.Add(new Foo { ID = r.Next() });
```

... and lastly, timed the code:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
bool b = list.Any(i => list.Where(j => i != j).Any(j => j.ID == i.ID));
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
b = (list.GroupBy(i => i.ID).Count() != list.Count);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

Here's one output:

> False
>
> 59392129
>
> False
>
> 168151

So I think it's safe to say that grouping and then comparing the count of groups to the count of items is way, *way* faster than doing a brute-force "nested Any" comparison.

Answer (score 2):

My take (no counting!):

```
var duplicates = agents
  .GroupBy(a => a.ID)
  .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any());
```

Comment: This statement returns the duplicates, not whether there are duplicates. I could stop as soon as Any duplicate has been found = your statement followed by Any(); Compared this method with the Distinct/Count method. Used sequence = new int[]{1}.Concat(Enumerable(0, 10000000); Alas the groupby method is 6 times slower. Could this be because the GroupBy is performed completely, even though a duplicate has already been found?

Comment: @HaraldDutch correct.  Even though GroupBy is lazy, it is fully evaluated when evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var agent in Agents) {
    if(Agents.Count(a => a.ID == agent.ID) > 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", agent.ID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool b = list.Any(i => list.Any(j => j.ID == i.ID && j != i));
```

That's a bit of a brute-force approach but it works. There might be a smarter way to do it using the Except() extension method.

Edit: You didn't actually say that you needed to know *which* items are "duplicated", only that you needed to know whether any where. This'll do the same thing except give you a list you can iterate over:

list.Where(i => list.Any(j => j.ID == i.ID && j != i))

I like the grouping approach too (group by ID and find the groups with count > 1).

Answer (score 0):

this is how i would do it without the need to do group-by in one line:

```
 List<Agent> duplicates = new HashSet<Agent>(agents.Where(c => agents.Count(x => x.ID == c.ID) > 1)).ToList();
```