# LINQ sorting. How to determine equality for multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, equality

I'm sorting multiple fields with LINQ. But how can I determine if two or more entries in the List are equal? That is, all fields are equal and sorting order will not change because of equality.

```
public List<SfpDb.ResultatViewRang> sortResMest(List<SfpDb.ResultatViewRang> resultat)
{
    return resultat
                    .OrderBy(p => p.statdsq)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.statdns)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.statdnf)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.totsum)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.totOmskyting)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.totinnertreff)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr10)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr9)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr8)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr7)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr6)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr5)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr4)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr3)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr2)
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.sumr1)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.perTreffRangStr)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.enavn, strCompareNo)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.fnavn, strCompareNo)
                    .ToList<SfpDb.ResultatViewRang>();
}
```

The content is from a database which holds results from a competition, and is sorted according to the competition rules. The sorting is used to determine which position the competitors get.

According to the rules, if one ore more competitors have the same values from the competition (p.totsum, p.totOmskyting, .....), they get the same position. Eg:
1. Jim Harris, 580, 25, 32, .....
2. Tom Jensen, 560, 20, 30, .....
3. Jean Johnson, 523, 23, 26, .....
3. Roy Beeman, 523, 23, 26, .....
5. Doug Wilson, 520, 23, 26, .....

The problem I have after sorting, is that I'm not sure how to identify the two persons in position 3 in this example.

In generic terms, having the following class:

```
public class MigrObject
{
    public int first { get; set; }
    public int second { get; set; }
    public int third { get; set; }
}
```

It would be sorted using

```
.OrderByDescending(p => p.first)
.ThenByDescending(p => p.second)
.ThenByDescending(p => p.third)
```

Having the following records: (first, second, third)
580, 25, 32
560, 30, 30
523, 23, 26
523, 23, 26
523, 23, 26
520, 23, 26
518, 40, 30
518, 40, 30
430, 14, 16

How do you identify the records that are equal? After processing the records, it should have the following positions/order:
1: 580, 25, 32
2: 560, 30, 30
3: 523, 23, 26
3: 523, 23, 26
3: 523, 23, 26
6: 520, 23, 26
7: 518, 40, 30
7: 518, 40, 30
9: 430, 14, 16

According to the international rules, the participants will be sorted by the value in the first field(first). If there is a tie, the second column will be compared, so we sort on "second". If there is still a tie, the third column will be compared, so we sort on "third". If any ties remain, the athletes must have the same ranking and must be listed in Latin alphabetical order using the athlete’s family name.

If the positions after the processing is 1,2,3,3,3,6,7 or 1,2,3,3,3,4,5 is not important. **The main problem is knowing if there is any ties left after comparing all the fields**, and which records are involved.

I was hoping that there were some features within LINQ which allowed you to be notified if all compared fields are equal.

Comment: You can use `Distinct` or `GroupBy` method.

Comment: _"all fields are equal and sorting order will not change because of equality"_ -- why do you care? how do you intend to use the equality? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do. Explain precisely and specifically what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: try checking this http://stackoverflow.com/q/312024/3956100 im sure you can change the IComparer in the linq to suit your needs.

Comment: You question is not clear. As far as I can understand, all you need to do is  get the sum of  `p.totsum, p.totOmskyting, p.totinnertreff` and order it by desc order. You can also add order by to 'name' just to show that people who have equal marks are sorted based on the alphabetical order.

Comment: I think the question is incorrect, and as the result you want to see 2 people at the same position (number 3 in your example). That position can be computed when you go through results of your LINQ query, so it has nothing to do with LINQ query itself. However, I don't understand why you have position #5 after #3, shouldn't that be #4?

Comment: @SergeSemenov - This is a sporting event rank if there are 5 competitors and two tie for position 3 then the next competitor is considered to be 5th, not 4th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.
I've tested and it works.

```
public class Program
    {
        public class TestData
        {
            public int First { get; set; }
            public int Second { get; set; }
            public int Third { get; set; }
            public int Place { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new List<TestData>
            {
                new TestData {First = 580, Second = 25, Third = 32},
                new TestData {First = 560, Second = 30, Third = 30},
                new TestData {First = 523, Second = 23, Third = 26},
                new TestData {First = 523, Second = 23, Third = 26},
                new TestData {First = 523, Second = 23, Third = 26},
                new TestData {First = 520, Second = 23, Third = 26},
                new TestData {First = 518, Second = 40, Third = 30},
                new TestData {First = 518, Second = 40, Third = 30},
                new TestData {First = 430, Second = 14, Third = 16}
            };

            var sorted =
                (from d in data
                    orderby d.First descending, d.Second descending, d.Third descending 
                    group d by d.First.ToString() + d.Second + d.Third into gd
                    select gd.ToList())
                    .ToList();

            var result = new List<TestData>();
            var place = 1;
            foreach (var sd in sorted)
            {
                sd.ForEach(p => p.Place = place);
                result.AddRange(sd);
                place += sd.Count;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A slight issue - `d.First.ToString() + d.Second + d.Third` will fail if the numbers are `{ 52, 32, 326 }` and `{523, 23, 26 }`. You should perhaps put in a divider. Something like `$"{d.First}:{d.Second}:{d.Third}"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this: (I am using your `MigrObject` example for simplicity)

```
Dictionary<MigrObject, int> orderedResult = new Dictionary<MigrObject, int>(); //reverse dictionary where int is the 'order' you want
foreach (var item in resultat) // assuming resultat is a List of MigrObject
{
    int order = 1;
    if(!orderedResult.Any(o => o.first == item.first && o.second == item.second && o.third == item.third)) // I don't use ContainsKey(item) because it may not work for custom defined classes as key
    {
        orderedResult.Add(item, order);
        count++;
    }
    else
        orderedResult.Add(item, order);
}
```

It may look complicated, but here is the explanation:

-The dictionary is reversed since we can have multiple values for the same key but no the other way around

-Start the order at 1 since there is no 0th place (in your example)

-Check if the dictionary contains a record for each item: If no, add it and increment count by 1, and if yes, do not increment count (thus giving the 2 duplicates same order)

-This assumes the `resultat` List is sorted correctly.

-This method may get complicated when you have a lot of fields to compare, but you can modify it if you have a better comparison method.

**Finally** you can loop over the dictionary and each item's "positions/order" is its value, and you can add this to an array, or whichever data type you want. (*Except dictionaries since the keys must be unique*)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You do know that yours doesn't compile and that you can't use `MigrObject` as a key to a dictionary?

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this. If I have to loop through the list, this might work.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it this way:

```
var scores = new [] { 580, 560, 523, 523, 523, 520, 518, 518, 430, };

var results =
    scores
        .OrderByDescending(x => x) // just in case scores not in order
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Aggregate(
            new { Rank = 1, Results = new List<Tuple<int, int>>() },
            (a, gx) =>
            {
                a.Results.AddRange(gx.Select(x => Tuple.Create(a.Rank, x)));
                return new { Rank = a.Rank + gx.Count(), Results = a.Results };
            })
        .Results;
```

I get the following result:

[image: result]

You would need to adjust the code to suit your input.

Comment: If the down-voter would respond I'd love to know what I've done wrong?

Comment: I believe the question poster downvotes the answers he does not like (yours works, and although way more complex, so does mine).

Comment: @Enigmativity : Your one works. You may need to check the performance of it though.

Comment: @KosalaW - What's wrong with the performance? Should be quite good, even for large lists.

Comment: By the look of it, yours has more reads. Ex: `gx.Count(), gx.Select()`. I just did a performance test for your code. It takes about 20ms. Whereas my one takes about 3ms (that's including adding test data to the list, printing output etc). So with large lists, your code will have a serious issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity 20ms for 9 items, is a big deal. That means 2.2secs for 1000 items. 22s for 10,000 items.

Comment: @KosalaW -  I don't know what you're running this on. My timings were 10 in 0.0082ms, 100 in 0.0621ms, 1,000 in 0.2965ms, 10,000 in 2.7475ms, 100,000 in 36.5582ms.

Comment: I ran it in on very decent computer. But surely you can run it on a computer that has got 100x processing power than mine and get those results. I will let OP to verify and decide.